# Strange output to txt file?

Tags: python, python-2.7

I'm trying to measure distance between CA atoms in a particular PDB file. The output appears as it should in Spyder, but the written text file appears strange and I don't know how to search for what the output is because I honestly do not know what it is written in. Below is my code:

```
import sys
import os
from Bio.PDB.PDBParser import PDBParser
import numpy as np
import warnings
def plot(data):    

# import matplotlib # matplotlib.use( 'Agg' ) 
import pylab

fig = pylab.figure()
ax = fig.add_subplot(111)

cax = ax.imshow(data, interpolation='nearest')
ax.set_title('Ca-Ca distance plot')

# Add colorbar, make sure to specify tick locations to match desired ticklabels 
min = np.min(data)
max = np.max(data)
cbar = fig.colorbar(cax, ticks=[min, max])
cbar.set_ticks([min,max])

pylab.show()
# pylab.savefig( 'distmat.png', format='png' ) 

if __name__ == '__main__':


fnam = 'myfile.pdb'
if not os.path.exists(fnam):
    print "file not found"
    raise SystemExit

id = 'myfile'

warnings.simplefilter('ignore')
parser = PDBParser()

s = parser.get_structure(id, fnam)

chains = [c for c in s.get_chains()]

x = []
for r in chains[0]:
    if 'CA' in r.child_dict:
        ca = r.child_dict['CA']
        x.append(ca.get_coord())

coords = np.array(x)
print (coords)
import scipy.spatial
data = scipy.spatial.distance.cdist(coords, coords, 'euclidean')
print data.shape
plot(data)
print(data)
with open('some file.txt', 'w') as f:
    f.write(data)
    f.close()
```

Below is part of the output. What is it and how do I fix it? Thank you for your help!:

```
    ‹ñ:(tO@m f\⁄l@cÿÖ∂r!@Â˛«1pi"@ß!•=E6'@=∫;oÆ)@cQ¥Ë¢a(@O)[hÉû/@Æ$≠€781@‹∞'å©X1@x±Mjû+@…‘0™û¥)@Ø1”P/@·uùπ„,@SrÆ¡·˙%@-‰Ÿ^>Â*@QCy‘O/@B?˜+@ÍµøµÇ|'@e∫≤òÌÄ.@ú?1@Õú…È.@«wX˜¥,@´i¥Ç–è+@◊s°(¯%@Î˛ø¶·+@¨ÉSÎ¯z.@k`rÕ=C(@åÜªÆ'@ï¯ÛU’.@kc÷é.@(¢·F£%*@óqÖîMµ0@Xö1Â
```

[image: Here is before]

[[image: Here is after data = scipy.spatial.distance.cdist(coords, coords, 'euclidean')[2]]

Comment: It appears that there is some special encoding/formatting when you run this:
data = scipy.spatial.distance.cdist(coords, coords, 'euclidean')

Take some time to start a debugger and go to that line. See what the data looks like before and after that line. Realistically, you will likely need to format this data on your own into something that you want the file to look like. For the sake of this post, add in what the data looks like before and after the previously mentioned command so we can come up with an answer for you

Comment: The coordinates themselves appear as vectors [[49.2  40.58 52.52]
 [47.66 41.88 49.3 ]
 [45.08 39.96 47.27]
 [46.54 41.05 43.89]
 [49.83 40.08 42.25]
 [48.9  42.28 39.19]
 [49.8  46.03 38.82]
 [46.98 48.53 39.58]
 [44.7  48.67 36.51]
 [41.21 50.38 36.49]
 [39.55 46.95 35.96]
 [41.81 45.25 38.59]
 [41.09 48.03 41.16]
 [37.31 47.71 40.48]
 [37.53 43.9  40.93]
 [39.71 44.25 44.11]
 [37.01 46.62 45.5 ]
 [34.03 44.43 44.4 ]
 [35.49 41.23 46.  ]
 [36.55 42.87 49.35]
....

Comment: Try if you can convert it to type `str`, do `f.write(str(data))`

Comment: If I do it as a string: [[ 0.          3.79868513  6.70233501 ... 28.54028785 31.17109105
  33.71138252]
 [ 3.79868513  0.          3.80311615 ... 25.0600631  27.79657606
  30.18632201]
 [ 6.70233501  3.80311615  0.         ... 23.25000058 25.720214
  27.9951571 ]
 ...
 [28.54028785 25.0600631  23.25000058 ...  0.          3.89616439
   5.9025497 ]
 [31.17109105 27.79657606 25.720214   ...  3.89616439  0.
   3.90325324]
 [33.71138252 30.18632201 27.9951571  ...  5.9025497   3.90325324
   0.        ]]

Comment: Are the other distances "hidden" from the command line window?

Comment: I notice in your code this line: `print data.shape`.  I don't know what `data` is, but I know it's not a `str`, as `str` objects don't have any `.shape` attribute or method.  So later when you write to a file with `f.write(data)`, I know it's not writing out text, because we know that `data` isn't a string.  Did you intend to write out text?  If so, writing out `data` isn't what you want.

Comment: Oh that makes sense! I'm wanting to write out the distance matrix I computed to a text file. The portion of the code that does the distance matrix is: scipy.spatial.distance.cdist(coords, coords, 'euclidean') How would I make it output in a way I can capture everything and write it to a text file?

Comment: Its as simple as accessing the individual elements of the coordinates matrix and formatting your own output to print to a file. If you dont want to do that yourself, see if there is any documentation within the lib that you use to see how they do it